# Negate echo statement and convert to value?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [capturing echo into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778336/capturing-echo-into-a-variable)

I have a function that echos a string. Is their any way (besides altering the function) that I can negate the echo statement?

example:

```
function echo_string(){
  echo "This is a string";
}

$dont_echo = negate_echo(echo_string());

$dont_echo .= ", a negated string";

echo $dont_echo; // "This is a string, a negated string";
```

Is their anything like `negate_echo`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ob_start();
echo_string();
$buffer = ob_get_clean();
```

That is: Starting a new [output buffer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.outcontrol.php), execute the function, get the buffers content and close it. See [`ob_get_clean`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php).

Answer (score 2):

The only way is to use output buffering:

```
ob_start();
echo_string();
$output = ob_get_clean();

echo $output.", a negated string";
```