# How to start ob_start() in parent ob_start's callback

Tags: php, ob-start

I have this code

```php
<?php
function testFunc($b){
    ob_start();
    echo "print from callback\n";
    return ob_get_clean();
}

ob_start('testFunc');
echo 'print from buffer';
ob_end_flush();
```

But I have a following error `ob_start(): Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers`

I expected the result

```
print from callback
```

Please, dont suggest simplify this code, because in my codebase I have nested buffers like this

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936067/cannot-use-output-buffering-in-output-buffering-display-handlers " if you remove the ob_start() from the callback function it's OK"

Comment: @Monnomcjo, yes it will work, but how do I print a text via `echo` inside callback?

Comment: With a callback you can't. But your callback function can return a string, html, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [capturing echo into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/778336/capturing-echo-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 0):

As said. "*You're trying to start a output buffer inside a buffer callback. If you use this code, it will generate that error. But if you remove the ob_start() from the callback function it's OK.*"

And, if you expected the result to print, return the string or anything else you want to print:

```
function testFunc($b){
    //ob_start();
    return "print from callback\n";
    //return ob_get_clean();
}

ob_start('testFunc');
echo 'print from buffer';
ob_end_flush();
```

Comment: I can't return a string here. Imagine, I have some "component" which prints html to the screen. I need buffer this component, and return its output as a result callback function

Comment: Your callback function returns what you want. Including html. However your request is "I expected the result: print from callback".